# Vue: add multiply alerts with quick actions

Tags: css, vue.js, dom

I have a question how to multiply alerts?
I have vue ts setup application, using Tailwind and daisy UI. I have a toggle element (link/unlink), API call and alert if success/error. Everything works fine except the moment if I toggle fast and first alert is still shown, the second alert will not appear. It only works if I wait until previous alert disappear, then trigger action, then new appear. Not if I do it fast

my template:

```
 <div
  class="alert alert-success z-[9999] fixed top-[-70px] left-0"
  id="alert-success"
>
  <span> {{ t('alerts.success') }}! {{ alertMsg }} </span>
</div>
```

style:

```
.show-alert {
 animation: mymove 5s ease-out forwards;
}
@keyframes mymove {
 0% {
  top: -70px;
 }
 30% {
  top: 10px;
 }
 70% {
  top: 10px;
 }
 100% {
  top: -70px;
  }
 }
```

function:

```
export  const showAlert = (response: boolean) => {
 var alertSuccess = document.getElementById(`alert-success`) as HTMLElement
 var alertError = document.getElementById('alert-error') as HTMLElement
 if (response) {
   alertSuccess.classList.add('show-alert')
 } else {
   alertError.classList.add('show-alert')
 }
 setTimeout(() => {
   alertSuccess.classList.remove('show-alert')
   alertError.classList.remove('show-alert')
 }, 5000)
}
```

I tried to generate an unique id for alert element each time i trigger the function, simply

```
const alertId = ref(0)
```

Then alert element has dynamic   :id="`alert-success-${alertId}`"
And when func is triggered add:

```
alertId.value += 1
```

But this way DOM return a null element. Plus as my alert el has z-index, I probably need to increase z-index for every new success alert if i want it on top of each other.

I also tried to start showAlert func by

```
alertSuccess.style.display = 'none' (to make old alert disappear) then
alertSuccess.style.display = 'block' (to make new alert appear)
```

but nothing happens

Is there an efficient way to achieve it?

Comment: Just a guess. Every alert has the same CSS, so maybe the alerts hide behind each other. Try removing the CSS and inspecting the results.

Comment: but i tried with display:none. Animation is still happening. It doesn't dissapear. I also tried to give initially top: -70px, so return it to far top to start new animation. Dosn't work neither

Comment: itried to start func with  alertSuccess.classList.remove('show-alert'), then add it, but doen't remove consistently. Smthg shows/dissaperas on its own

Comment: There doesn't appear to be code here capable of generating multiple alert divs. Changing the id does not generate new HTML.  If you could look at the DOM when two alerts are active, you would expect to see two separate alert `<div>` elements. There's nothing here I see that does that, you're just trying to hide the "first" alert and then immediately show the same one again.  Also, if you're using `document` interface (i.e. getElementById) in a Vue app, you're probably doing something wrong.  There is `v-if` and dynamic class binding you should use instead